# How to draw an image inside a html canvas with JavaScript for special filters

Tags: javascript, css, image, image-processing, html5-canvas

I have succeeded in applying CSS pencil-effect to an image from this great [site](https://bennettfeely.com/image-effects/). I need to replicate the effect using JavaScript drawImage inside a HTML canvas.

The context (CanvasRenderingContext2D) draws the image using the filter property, but I could not set to the context background-size, background-image, background-blend-mode, background-position.
I need the final filtered image to be saved in the database. The image processing must be on the browser and not on server-side.

Any working snippet is really useful.

Thank you!

```js
//  Must be onload, otherwise canvas is not ready
window.onload = function() {

    let imageWidth = 800
    let imageHeight = 600

    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    canvas.width = imageWidth
    canvas.height = imageHeight

    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let img = new Image() 
    img.width = imageWidth
    img.height = imageHeight
    img.src = "https://bennettfeely.com/image-effects/css/photo.jpg"

    let cssfilter = "brightness(2) invert(1) grayscale(1)" 
    context.filter = cssfilter 
          
    /*
    // Tried, but it does not work
    img.style.backgroundSize = "cover"
    img.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://bennettfeely.com/image-effects/css/photo.jp'), url('https://bennettfeely.com/image-effects/css/photo.jp')"
    img.style.backgroundPosition = "calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% - 1px), calc(50% + 1px) calc(50% + 1px)"
  
    // img.style = "background-blend-mode: difference; background-position: calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% - 1px), calc(50% + 1px) calc(50% + 1px); filter: brightness(2) invert(1) grayscale(1); box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;"
            */

    // Draw image
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)
}
```

```css
@supports (filter: invert(1)) and (background-blend-mode: difference) {
    .pencil-effect {
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url("https://bennettfeely.com/image-effects/css/photo.jpg"), url("https://bennettfeely.com/image-effects/css/photo.jpg");
        background-blend-mode: difference;
        background-position: calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% - 1px), calc(50% + 1px) calc(50% + 1px);
        filter: brightness(2) invert(1) grayscale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="original-img" src="https://bennettfeely.com/image-effects/css/photo.jpg" width="800" height="600">
<img class="pencil-effect" width="800" height="600">
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: red"></canvas>
```

Comment: _“but I could not set to the context background-size, background-image, background-blend-mode, background-position”_ - of course you can’t, because you are not dealing with a background image any more here. You would need to _calculate_ what these properties do yourself here for the most part.

Comment: You might be able to render a div with background-image to a canvas using a library like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect from the 2D context API by reproducing what your CSS is doing, step by step.

The first step is to draw the image (first background image) with an offset of -1 -1.
This can be easily achieved by using [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  const imageWidth = 800
  const imageHeight = 600
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = imageWidth;
  canvas.height = imageHeight;
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// first pass without any filter nor blending
  // simple offset
  context.drawImage(img, -1, -1, imageWidth, imageHeight)
};
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg/593px-Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: red"></canvas>
```

The second step is to blend this image with a copy of itself with a slight offset in the other direction.
The `difference` blending mode is also available in the 2d context API through its [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property:

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  const imageWidth = 800
  const imageHeight = 600
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = imageWidth;
  canvas.height = imageHeight;
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// first pass without any filter nor blending
  // simple offset
  context.drawImage(img, -1, -1, imageWidth, imageHeight)
// second pass, do the blending without filter
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'difference';
  // note how we draw the canvas over itself with the counter offset
  context.drawImage(img, 1, 1, imageWidth, imageHeight);
};
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg/593px-Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: red"></canvas>
```

The last step is to apply the CSS-filter `brightness(2) invert(1) grayscale(1)` on this blended image.
And once again, the 2D context API can do it, through its [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property.

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  const imageWidth = 800
  const imageHeight = 600
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = imageWidth;
  canvas.height = imageHeight;
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const cssfilter = "brightness(2) invert(1) grayscale(1)" 

// first pass without any fiter nor blending
  // simple offset
  context.drawImage(img, -1, -1, imageWidth, imageHeight)
// second pass, do the blending without filter
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'difference';
  // note how we draw the canvas over itself with the counter offset
  context.drawImage(img, 1, 1, imageWidth, imageHeight);

// third pass, apply the filter on the blended result
  context.filter = cssfilter;
  // since there is no transparency we could also have set it to 'source-over'
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  // here we don't set any offset: we only apply the filter
  context.drawImage(context.canvas, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)
};
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg/593px-Point_Reyes_Lighthouse_%28April_2012%29.jpg";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: red"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido for the the working snippet and for the comments, it really helped me! Although the pictures are not exactly the same, I will play with the filter options to obtain the desired effect.

Comment: @CristianGhinea there was a typo / brain-fart in my answer... Sorry. In the second pass, we should use the <img> not the <canvas>, to avoid drawing the already offset image...